# Close specific pdf files

Tags: excel, vba

I use this function to close adobe reader

```
Sub TerminateProcess()
Dim strTerminateThis As String
Dim objWMIcimv2 As Object
Dim objProcess As Object
Dim objList As Object
Dim intError As Integer

'Process to terminate
strTerminateThis = "AcroRd32.exe"

'Connect to CIMV2 Namespace
Set objWMIcimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

'Find the process to terminate
Set objList = objWMIcimv2.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='" & strTerminateThis & "'")

'Terminates a process and all of its threads.
For Each objProcess In objList
    intError = objProcess.Terminate
Next

Set objWMIcimv2 = Nothing
Set objList = Nothing
Set objProcess = Nothing
End Sub
```

Is it possible to edit it so I can close specific pdf files and not all files?

Thank u in advance.